# JavaFX Duplicate children PieChart

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing a program in which on button click data in a pie chart rotates (slice on 10-12 o'clock moves to 12-2 etc). Code below (kinda) works, it rotates, but eats the temp slice and creates whole paragraph of errors. It is my first time trying JavaFX and I'm not really sure how to manage that.

```java
    private BorderPane layout;
    private Scene scene;

    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("Post-production age", 424236),
                    new PieChart.Data("Production age", 1030060),
                    new PieChart.Data("Production age2", 1030060),
                    new PieChart.Data("Production age3", 1030060),
                    new PieChart.Data("Pre-production age", 310319));
    PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        layout = new BorderPane();
        scene = new Scene(layout,720,480);
        stage.setTitle("People");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("rotate");
        layout.setBottom(button);
        layout.setCenter(chart);
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            rotate();
        });

        chart.setStartAngle(90);
        chart.setTitle("Economical age groups");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public  void rotate(){

        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartDataTemp = pieChartData;
        int sizeOne = pieChartDataTemp.size();
        PieChart.Data tempData = pieChartDataTemp.get(sizeOne-1);
         pieChartDataTemp.add(0,tempData);
         if(pieChartDataTemp.size()>sizeOne) pieChartDataTemp.remove(pieChartDataTemp.size()-1 );

        PieChart chartTemp = new PieChart(pieChartDataTemp);
        layout.setCenter(chartTemp);
        chartTemp.setStartAngle(90);

    }
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Chart$1@5cfeee33[styleClass=chart-content]
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:558)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.dataItemAdded(PieChart.java:417)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.lambda$new$0(PieChart.java:168)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at task.Main.rotate(Main.java:54)
    at task.Main.lambda$start$0(Main.java:39)
(...and so on)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Some Background

JavaFX charts support animation when data is added, removed, or updated. However, when animation is enabled, the [nodes used to actually display the data](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.Data.html#nodeProperty) aren't removed from the chart until the animation completes—which is not something publicly observable. This means you can't just remove a `PieChart.Data` and then immediately re-add it, as you're currently doing. Attempting to do that results in trying to add a `Node` to a `Parent` when said `Node` is still currently a child of said `Parent`. As the `IllegalArgumentException` you get says, [duplicate children are not allowed](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren()).

---

## Issues in Your Code

You have this code (from `#rotate()`):

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartDataTemp = pieChartData;
int sizeOne = pieChartDataTemp.size();
PieChart.Data tempData = pieChartDataTemp.get(sizeOne - 1);
pieChartDataTemp.add(0,tempData);
if (pieChartDataTemp.size() > sizeOne) {
    pieChartDataTemp.remove(pieChartDataTemp.size() - 1);
}

PieChart chartTemp = new PieChart(pieChartDataTemp);
layout.setCenter(chartTemp);
chartTemp.setStartAngle(90);
```

Both `pieChartDataTemp` and `pieChartData` refer to the same `ObservableList`. So when you add `tempData` at the `0` index you're actually adding the element to the current `PieChart` while it's still present at the `size() - 1` index. I tried to fix this by swapping the `add` and `remove` calls but that didn't fix the problem—that's how I found out the animations were getting in the way.

You also create a new `PieChart` and replace the old one. This is not necessary, assuming I properly understand what you're trying to do. It may also cause problems since you're using the same `ObservableList` for each `PieChart`.

---

## Solutions

There are at least two solutions.

#### Disable Animations

One fix is to simply [disable animations](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#animatedProperty):

```
yourPieChart.setAnimated(false);
```

#### Copy the `PieChart.Data`

The other option is to create a new `PieChart.Data` from the old one. Here's an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> createChartData() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Post-production age", 424236),
                new PieChart.Data("Production age", 1030060),
                new PieChart.Data("Production age2", 1030060),
                new PieChart.Data("Production age3", 1030060),
                new PieChart.Data("Pre-production age", 310319)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        PieChart chart = new PieChart(createChartData());
        chart.setStartAngle(90.0);

        Button rotateBtn = new Button("Rotate");
        rotateBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
            event.consume();
            PieChart.Data removed = chart.getData().remove(chart.getData().size() - 1);
            chart.getData().add(0, new PieChart.Data(removed.getName(), removed.getPieValue()));
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, rotateBtn, new Separator(), chart);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

The rotate code is in the `onAction` handler of the button:

```
rotateBtn.setOnAction(event -> {
    event.consume();
    PieChart.Data removed = chart.getData().remove(chart.getData().size() - 1);
    chart.getData().add(0, new PieChart.Data(removed.getName(), removed.getPieValue()));
});
```

Note I don't create another `PieChart`.