# Getting Duplicate series error on second click for chart. How to resolve this?

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I am trying to get graphs on click of a button but if I click the button the second time it is throwing a duplicate series exception. can anyone help me with this?

thanks in advance

Tried:
1. series.getData().clear();

```
NumberAxis xaxis = new NumberAxis(2008,2018,1);  
NumberAxis yaxis = new NumberAxis(10,80,5);
                 xaxis.setLabel("Year");  
                 yaxis.setLabel("Price");

XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

LineChart linechart = new LineChart(xaxis,yaxis); 


graph1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
             @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                 Linechart(X,Y,xaxis,yaxis);
             }



private void Linechart(ArrayList <Integer> X, ArrayList<Integer> Y, NumberAxis xaxis, NumberAxis yaxis) {

                 series.getData().clear();

                 series.setName("Stock Analysis");  
                 for(int i=0;i<=X.size()-1;i++){
                     series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(X.get(i), Y.get(i)));
                 }
                 linechart.getData().add(series);
                 child2.getChildren().remove(area);
                 child2.getChildren().add(linechart);

             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is caused by adding the same `Series` instance to the same `Chart` a second time. Your method does not take into account if the series is already present in your chart, so invoking the method a second time naturally leads to the "duplicate series" error. Calling `series.getData().clear()` won't solve the problem because that clears the [*series'* data](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html#getData()), not the [*chart's* data](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#getData()). It's unfortunate they named both properties the same thing (i.e. `XYChart#getData()` and `Series#getData()`) as it can get confusing.

You have at least two potential solutions, assuming you continue using the same `Series` instance:

1. Remove the `Series` from the `LineChart`, update it, then add it back.

   ```java
   chart.getData().remove(series);
   // update series
   chart.getData().add(series); // side-effect: series moved to end of list
   ```

   <sup>***Note:** This option may not work if the chart is animated. See [JavaFX Duplicate Series Added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32151435/6395627) and [JavaFX Duplicate children PieChart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56743532/6395627).*</sup>
2. Simply don't add the `Series` to the `LineChart` if it's already present.

   ```java
   if (!chart.getData().contains(series)) {
     chart.getData().add(series);
   }
   ```

An alternative is to create and use a *new* `Series` instance, if appropriate.

Additionally, calling `child2.getChildren().add(linechart);` should also cause an exception to be thrown once your method is invoked a second time. At least, it will once you fix your current problem as the current exception stops that line from being executed. The same `Node` cannot be added to the same `Parent` multiple times—same problem, different(ish) context.

Your method appears to be trying to do too much. Conceptually, it looks like you want the method to *update* the chart. If that's the case then there's no need to "re-add" either the `Series` to the chart or the `LineChart` to the parent. Set up the user interface when first initializing everything, then just have the method update the data as needed. Doing it this way means the you don't have to use either of the above solutions; it's also a better way of doing things overall.

Also note that you're using [*raw types*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). The `LineChart`, `Series`, and `Data` classes are all generic but you don't specify any type arguments. Since both your axes are `NumberAxis` you should be using:

- `LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);`
- `Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();`
- `series.add(new Data<>(x.get(i), y.get(i)));` (notice the diamond operator: `<>`).

And finally, try to follow [Java naming conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming), especially when posting to a public forum.